# Custom forms are not visible in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have created a custom list and created some custom SharePoint Designer forms. Earlier these forms were visible in forms section in SharePoint Designer 2010 but now only default forms are visible. When I try to create a new form with similar names it gives me an error that "Could not save the list changes to the Server. The File exist."

Can anyone help me out why the forms are not visible in Designer? or How can I retrieve them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look for the forms in Designer: All Items  > Lists > Your List name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. Details are as below:

**Problem:**

1. I created Custom forms for my custom list by following below steps,

   i) Open site in SharePoint Designer 2010

   ii) Browse the List in which custom forms needs to be created.

   iii) Create New/Edit/Display form as per your need.
2. Now the actual problem was, that these forms were not visible to me in SharePoint Designer, But they were working fine while accessing from the URL. So, whenever I need to make any changes directly into the form I was unable to do that.

**Resolution:**

There is a work around to get your forms back into the Forms Section of your SharePoint Designer. Follow below steps:

1. Open Your Site in SharePoint Designer 2010.
2. Click on the **Lists and Libraries** from the left navigation panel.
3. Click on your list which has your Custom Forms.
4. Now click on the **Forms** Sections and it will display all the OOTB forms (NewForm.aspx, DispForm.aspx & EditForm.aspx)
5. Open any of the form in Advanced Mode.
6. Now from the Breadcrumb click on the arrow icon which is just next to your list name and it will display all the forms including your custom forms, as shown in below screen:

[image]

7. Click on your custom form which was missing and start working on that. That's it!